# Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type"

Tags: magento-1.9, import, importexport, dataflow

I know there are a few issues with this already, but I have tried some of the solutions.But they dont seem to work. Is there a default set of fields that the CSV must have. I have checked my CSV and all of the titles are in lower case, there are no spaces after each title, and the sku are unique.

Comment: best way is to use magmi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are some required columns in CSV. Check list below:

- type_id **OR** _type
- _attribute_set
- tax_class_id
- weight
- sku
- name
- price
- description
- short_description

Without the following fields, product will be created at database, but it won’t be visible to frontend :

- visibility
- _root_category
- _category
- _product_websites
- status
- qty
- is_in_stock

Comment: Thanks, I have the first set of bullet points, I have imported them through Data Profiles, imported successfully, however they are not showing in Magento back-end?

Answer (score 0):

- All required product attributes must be part of csv.
- Apart from that there are some other fields like category, websites must be part of csv (if you want to show product in frontend).

Note: Remember to save csv file with UTF-8 format only.